# what's the reference level when creating activity?

Tags: android

I know there is a three reference type when creating object, StrongReference, SoftReference and WeakReference.
I wonder what's the reference type when creating activity.
I can guess that the fragment can have a that three type like below.

```
val fragment = MyFragment()
    fragment = SoftReference(MyFragment())
    fragment = WeakReference(MyFragment())
```

But I don't think anything about activity.
Is there any way to check this even when using DI(dagger or hilt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities are StrongReference. The test you can do is create a VERY SLOW AsyncTask that holds an Activity reference and then finish() the Activity. If you can access Activity's variable from "AsyncTask.onPostExecute()" it means the reference is Strong.